# How can I set a directory permission so that all files, existing, and newly added are indelible?

Tags: file-permissions

I am tinkering with an app that I do not control. It creates files and then sometime later deletes them, I want to prevent it from being able to delete those files.  Or if I could create a file system watcher app that would auto copy the file to a new location, that too would suffice, but I do not know if that is possible on Android.  Also, I would like to be able to set this recursively on a small folder tree but if not, I can just do each folder manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: you *may* need to be rooted to do this, depending on where the app is writing these files - if you do, run `su` before running these commands)

Install a [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) on your phone. Once it's finished installing, open it up and type `cd /the/folder`.

If you have enough time to type in commands while the file exists simply type `chmod -R 444 .`, which will make the current directory and all subdirectories read-only.

If you don't have enough time, type something like this: `while true; do if ls | grep <filename>; then chmod -R 444 .; fi; done`. Leave it running in the terminal session and when the app creates <filename> it'll make the directory and its subdirectories read-only.

(All of the above can be run in `adb shell` if you prefer, but IMO installing a terminal emulator is less of a hassle)